# NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer error

Tags: spring-boot

After adding a set of Java classes to a runnable Spring Boot project, I get the following runtime error.

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv6Addresses
13:21:20.272 [Thread-0] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader - Created RestartClassLoader org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@26e4afa2
13:21:20.576 [restartedMain] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.representer.Representer: method 'void <init>()' not found
...
```

For the NoSuchMethodError, an incompatible library/dependence usually is the cause. I can't thinking of any added Java code would use the org.yaml.snakeyaml as it isn't in the build.gradle file. My IntelliJ Idea doesn't tell me the dependency chain leading to the dependency. The Spring Boot version is 2.7.3. the sankeyaml version is 1.30.

Comment: Currently there is an issue for this:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/34405

Comment: Thanks for the info. Many others have run into the same issue lately based on the ticket. Based on some posts on the ticket, the issue was resolved after I removed the jackson-dataformat-yaml dependency from the build file.